# what is nginx location ~* and ~

Tags: nginx

I am trying to understand nginx a little better and trying to form a regex where every url that does NOT match `/api/postdataV1` is routed to a different cluster of servers.  I keep seeing these two things in examples with no explanation

```
location ~ {some regex}

location ~* (some regex}
```

My first question is what are these `~` and `~*` (I think the `~` just means I am specifying a regex?) but what about `~*` then?

What I think what I want is this.  Would this be correct?

```
location ~ ^/api/postdataV1$ {
    #matches to this route to where I want
}

location / {
    #This will be everything except /api/postdataV1 I think
}
```

Would this be correct? but what about the `~*` ...I don't get that one

thanks,
Dean

Comment: [the wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration) is always worth a look first.

Comment: I had looked through the docs, but just didn't find the right links and ended up on the documentation page for "location" which really should have that information but didn't.  (wiki as I recall referred me to the documentation as being the most up to date).

Comment: i'd google `nginx location`, first hit is [this](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) :) but i must admit, one must get used to the nginx-documentation, esp. finding the right stuff below modules-section.

Comment: my google first page using your search query was exactly what I read the first time around... http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule which in RED says the article is obsolete leading me to another page  (you have to know google yeilds different results based on who you are-if logged in- and which server you end up hitting).  I did not get to the page given below at all which rocked using google and reading around :( !!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As stated in [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), `~*` regex is for case-insensitive matching and `~` are for case-sensitive.

Your syntax is ok, but it can be rewritten without regex (shortest location goes last in request matching):

```
location /api/postdata {
}

location / {
}
```

Comment: ah, cool...yeah, I tried googling ~* but google doesn't index special characters too well(too bad nginx didn't use directives instead as I probably would have landed right on that page)

Comment: @DeanHiller Looks like google fixed that bug :D

Comment: Your answer might not be correct as `/api/PostData` won't match without `~*`